# Custom Method in Rails Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**tl;dr the validation works in the browser, but fails with rspec. I'm not sure why.**

**answer:** I was attempting to mass assign user_id, but user_id wasn't mass-assignable. Was building it correctly in the controller, incorrectly in rspec.

This is my Listing model. Every listing has a price and a user_id associated with it.

In my "listing" model, I have "price".

In my "user" model I have a boolean attribute called "vip".

The max value for "price" depends on the User's VIP-status. If VIP, max price is 400. Else, max price is 200.

I wrote a method "listing_ceiling" that should return the correct max value depending on the user's VIP-ness.

It works in the browser, but when I run through my tests, rspec comes back with the error:

```
undefined method `vip?' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not exactly sure where I'm falling short here. It works correctly in the browser, but fails when testing with rspec. Here's the code:

```
validates_numericality_of :price, :presence => true, :greater_than => 10, :less_than => :listing_ceiling

def listing_ceiling
    if self.user.vip?
        400.01
    else
        200.01
    end
end
```

Any ideas why it would fail this way?

Comment: When rspec runs, it uses a test database. Are you sure you have users in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Listing#user` returns `nil`. There could be two problems.

1. Your listing does not have a user. i.e. foreign key `user_id` is `nil` for the `Listing` in question. OR
2. Your listing *has* a value in `user_id` column. But there is no `User` with that id.

Solution is to assign a user to your listing.

Comment: Close. I was manually assigning user_id, but user_id isn't mass-assignable. Therefore, no user!

Answer (score 1):

You should check your RSpec, the problem doesn't lie in your cutom validation method but in your test setup. As the error message states `user == nil`!

Comment: Bingo. The method in the model was right, so of course that would work in a browser. 

The problem was in rspec, like you said. 

I was trying to manually assign user_id, but it wasn't mass-assignable.